# User Input - DOS batch file

Tags: batch-file, dos

I get a bat file as below:

```
@ECHO Executing scripts...
PAUSE 

for %%X in (*.SQL) do SQLCMD -S localhost -d CTL  -I -i "%%X" >> ResultScript.txt

pause
```

In this I want to has user inputs for localhost (Sql server instance) and CTL (database).
How can this be achieved in DOS (os: WinXP)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SET /P variable=PromptString
```

So your batch file would be something like this

```
@ECHO Executing scripts... 
PAUSE  
SET /P sqlServer=Please enter SQLServer: 
SET /P CTL=Please enter CTL:
for %%X in (*.SQL) do SQLCMD -S %sqlServer% -d %CTL%  -I -i "%%X" >> ResultScript.txt 

pause
```

Comment: How did you guess the exact user inputs I wanted? Spooky!

Answer (score 1):

Use parameter markers, where %1 refers to the first parameter, %2 the second, and so forth.:

```
for %%X in (*.SQL) do SQLCMD -S %1 -d %2  -I -i "%%X" >> ResultScript.txt
```

If your batch file was called ExecScript.bat, your user would run it as

```
ExecScript instancename databasename
```

You'll probably want to add a test above the for loop to make sure both parameters are passed in. Running SQLCMD with a blank instance and database wouldn't work too well.