# Is a way to compile a .java file using batch, but so that the batch file can be reused?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, batch-file

IS there a way to make a batch file that:
1. Opens cmd
2. asks for a filepath
3. complies the targeted file
4. runs the product
I know how to do this like so:

```
@echo off
javac Filename.java
java  Filename
```

The only prolems are:
1. i want to make it reusable (so that it asks for a filepath)
2. the window briefly shows the error that javac is not a regonized command and then closes.
is there anyway to do what i want to do? I know that you can use some srt of set path command to fix this but nothing worked. if it helps my jdk is at C:/program Files/java/jdk1.7.0_10/bin

Comment: It sounds like you should be using an IDE.  When you want to make and run a program you press the `Run` button and when you want to debug you press the `Debug` button.

Comment: "I know that you can use some srt of set path command to fix this but nothing worked". That is ridiculous!  If you want our help, you better give us all the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at these questions:

[How to read input from console in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879791/how-to-read-input-from-console-in-a-batch-file)

[Problem with user input in my batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916413/problem-with-user-input-in-my-batch-file)

[how do i get a batch file to accept input from a txt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653371/how-do-i-get-a-batch-file-to-accept-input-from-a-txt-file)

[User Input - DOS batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876987/user-input-dos-batch-file)

and many more [...](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/userinput.php)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to look at existing build tools instead. Why? You ask for a reusable solution. From my experience, when it comes to building projects, once they become bigger, each has its own way. So a build tool has to be generic enough to satisfy all requirements. The solution that you provided in your question will not work for more complicated examples.

There are more sophisticated build tools out there but you may first look at Ant.